# Hochschild cohomology of the $A_\infty$-category of paths

Tags: homological-algebra, infinity-categories, hochschild-cohomology

I would like to describe the Hochschild cohomology (in the sense of $A_\infty$-categories) of the following $A_\infty$-category associated to a topological space $X$:

It has points of $X$ as objects.
The chain complex of morphisms from $a$ to $b$ is the (singular) cochain complex of the space of paths (in $X$) from $a$ to $b$. Higher composition operations are the natural ones (coming from the structure of $E_1$-algebroid on the path space of $X$).

In other words, this is the $A_\infty$ vesion of the $\infty$-groupoid associated to $X$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (Maybe you know all this.) Assuming $X$ connected, isn't your $A_\infty$-category equivalent to the $A_\infty$-algebra $C_*(\Omega X)$? One has for the Hochschild *homology* the Goodwillie isomorphism $HH_*(C_*\Omega X) \cong H_*(LX)$. So long as $X$ satisfies Poincare duality of degree $d$ (eg is a closed manifold of degree $d$), we then have an isomorphism $HH^*(C_*\Omega X) \cong HH_{*+d}(C_* \Omega X)$. I don't know what you can say when $X$ does not satisfy Poincare duality.